# screen tearing horizontal lines bug in ubuntu 20.04 while playing video or dragging window

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, video, intel-graphics

In my system I have intel HD Graphics 620.

When I play video or drag any window I see the horizontal lines on the screen like slices.
[horizonal lines while playing video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlC0D.jpg)

I tried one solution. i have edited `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` file content to

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

after this, my issue is solved but
I got green blocks on the screen every time I boot the system.

[green blocks on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06u3y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Solved by switching to Wayland in the login menu [Ubuntu on Wayland] on the bottom right of the login screen. I think this choice comes with Ubuntu 21.04, not sure.